# HTTP DELETE request with extra authentication

Tags: html, parameters, header, request, http-delete

I was searching for a solution of the following problem, so far without success: I'm planning a RESTful web service, where certain actions (e.g. DELETE) should require a special authentication.

The idea is, that users have a normal username/password login (session based or Basic Auth, doesn't really matter here) using which they can access the service. Some actions require an additional authentication in form of a PIN code or maybe even a one-time password. Including the extra piece of authentication into the login process is not possible (and would miss the point of the whole exercise).

I thought about special headers (something like X-OTP-Authetication) but that would make it impossible to access the service via a standard HTML page (no means to include a custom header into a link).
Another option was HTTP query parameters, but that seems to be discouraged, especially for DELETE.

Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Have you considered [OAuth](http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/)? It contains some extended authentication and support known providers such as facebook, google and microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

From [REST Web Service Security with jQuery Front-End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416229/rest-web-service-security-with-jquery-front-end)

> If you haven't already, I'd recommend some reading on [OAuth 1.0](http://oauth.net/) and [2.0](http://oauth.net/2/). They are both used by some of the bigger API, such as Facebook, Netflix, Twitter, and more. 2.0 is still in draft, but that hasn't stopped anyone from implementing it and using it as it is more simple for a client to use. It sounds like you want something more complicated and more secure, so you might want to focus on 1.0.
>
> I always found Netflix's [Authentication Overview](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/read/Security) to be a good explanation for clients.

Comment: As I get OAuth, this is designed for a 3 party setup where the user wants some website to access his data on a webservice without revealing his password. What I am looking for is different. User authentication is fully under my control, just some operations require an additional piece of identification (e.g. a one-time password generated by a hardware token). Anyhow, thanks for your hint and I'll have a closer look into OAuth, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Fair enough. It might be a little overkill for just an internal service, but it can be used that way (our mobile app uses it to authenticate with our public API). I'm most familiar with 2.0, but it runs on the idea of a token (like a session key) that has a scope. You could do a similar pattern so some DELETEs take one scope and more protected DELETEs could take a different scope that has to be requested by the client application separately.